# Consumindo webservice JSON com a utilização do AsyncTaks

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Bom, estou tentando fazer um aplicativo que faça um login em uma base de dados, anteriormente estava utilizando o metodo de thread para conseguir, esta funcionando, porem na hora de informar as mensagens de erro na tela, ou coisa do tipo, não estava conseguinte. Modifiquei para utilizar asyncTaks, porem está continuando a da erro.

LOG UTILIZANDO ASSYNC:

```
05-25 08:32:14.444    4091-4091/com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas, PID: 4091
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
        at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas.Connection.getSetDataWeb(Connection.java:31)
        at com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas.MainActivity.callServer(MainActivity.java:121)
        at com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:17)
        at com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Meu codigo do main está assim:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hs_cell);

    //Chamar os objetos
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TXT_EMAIL_LOGIN);
    senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TXT_SENHA_LOGIN);
    cod_igrej = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.COD_IGREJ_LOGIN);
    entrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN_ENTRA_APLIC);
    sair = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN_SAIRX_APLIC);



    entrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Usuario usr = new Usuario();

            String json = generateJson(usr);
            callServer("send-json", json);

        }
    });
```

E a parte do callServer:

```
private void callServer(final String method, final String data){
    final ProgressDialog progresso = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progresso.setMessage("Entrando");
    progresso.show();
     asw = Connection.getSetDataWeb("http://192.168.1.20/renan/process.php", method, data);

    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){



        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progresso.setMessage("Aguarde");

        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... asw){
            if(asw.equals("3"))
                progresso.setMessage("Creaódigo da igreja inesistente, por favor escreva um código válido.");
            else if (asw.equals("2")){
                progresso.setMessage("Senha incorreto, por favor escreva uma senha válida.");
                // makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha incorreto, por favor escreva uma senha válida.", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (asw.equals("1"))
            {
                progresso.setMessage("E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido.");
                // makeText(MainActivity.this, "E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido.", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(){

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(){
            progresso.setMessage("Seja Bem vindo.");
            progresso.show();
            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MC_Home.class);
            startActivity(it);
            progresso.dismiss();

        }



         /*public void run(){

            if (data.isEmpty()){
                degenerateJson(asw);
           }

             Atividade_Entrar(asw, null,null);
             //makeText(MainActivity.this, "Código da igreja inesistente, por favor escreva um código válido.", LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }*/
    }.execute();
   }
```

}

Classe `Conection`:

```
package com.example.hotsystems.hs_celulas;

import android.app.Activity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Connection extends Activity{
    public static String getSetDataWeb(String url, String method, String data){

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String answer = "";

        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> valores = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", method));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", data));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valores));
            HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            answer = EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        return(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A excepção *NetworkOnMainThreadException* é lançada quando um programa *target API level* 11 ou superior acede à internet na *application's main thread*.

Pelo que vejo no seu código o que provalvelmente (não sei o que é essa classe *Connection*) está a provocar isso é a linha:

```
asw = Connection.getSetDataWeb("http://192.168.1.20/renan/process.php", method, data);
```

Se for o caso, passá-la para dentro do método `doInBackground` poderá resolver o problema.

A partir da Api *level* 9, o Android, introduziu um [mecanismo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) para alertar o programador quando ele, inadvertidamente ou não, acede ao disco ou à rede(*network*) na *application's main thread*. Esse mecanismo lança uma excepção quando isso acontence.

Esse comportamento pode ser desabilitado colocando o seguinte código no método `onCreate()` da *Activity*:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

O código que está no método `getSetDataWeb()` tem de ser executado de forma assincrona, deve usar a sua *AsyncTask* para o executar.

Ela deverá ser qualquer coisa como isto:

```
private ProgressDialog progresso = new ProgressDialog(this);

private class GetSetDataWeb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private String url, method, data;

    public GetSetDataWeb(String url, String method, String data){
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progresso.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        progresso.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String answer = "";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try{
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> valores = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", method));
            valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", data));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valores));
            HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            answer = EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        return answer;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progresso.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("3")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Código da igreja inesistente, por favor escreva um código válido.", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
        }else if (result.equals("2")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Senha incorreto, por favor escreva uma senha válida.", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return;
        }else if (result.equals("1"))
        {
            progresso.setMessage("E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido.");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "E-mail incorreto, por favor escreva um email válido.",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Seja bem vindo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MC_Home.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }

}
```

Coloque esse código na *MainActivity* e para chamar o serviço faça assim:

```
new GetSetDataWeb("http://192.168.1.20/renan/process.php", method, data).execute();
```

Comment: Se caso eu coloco ele dentro do doInBackground, ele da um erro, e nao deixa eu nem compilar o programa. Incompatibilidade de tipos.

Comment: Que classe é essa: *Connection*?

Comment: É a classe que faz todo trabalho sujo, de realmente conectar ao webservice, e tal.

Comment: Então tem mesmo que ir para dentro do `doInBackgroud`. O que é que ela retorna?

Comment: Ele me retorna um numero, se for 3 é o codigo que esta errado, se for 2 é a senha e se for 1 é o email. Porem preciso mandar para ele o url, e tbem o methodo, alem da data, está data, é porque se for para mandar uma aquisição em forma de json. entendeu ?

Comment: Todo esse código que postou está na Activity Connection?

Comment: Sim, na verdade está na main, e tem uma classe connection, onde eu chamo ela para fazer o serviço.

Comment: por favor, deu tudo certo, porem no momento em que valida, e da errado ele entra no programa, como eu faço para quando ele validar e der errado, ele abortar, e nao deixar a pessoa acessa a pagina ?

Comment: Julgo que quando diz que entra na página se está a referir que entra na *Activity* *MC_Home*. Por lapso não incluí um `return` após cada *Toast*. No final de cada `if(result.equals())` é necessário colocar `return`

Comment: É para colocar so o return ? sem lugar link nenhum

Comment: Não percebi o que quer dizer. O que o código no `onPostExecute` faz é esconder o *ProgressDialog* e analisar o resultado. Caso seja 1,2 ou 3 mostra a mensagem correspondente utilizando um *Toast* e sai, caso não seja, mostar a mensagem "Seja bem vindo" e abre a *Activity MC_Home*.

Comment: Eu conceguir aqui, muito obrigado, você me ajudou muito nesta parte do meu projeto.